# Bootstrap how to get text to vertical align in a div container

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, vertical-alignment

What is the best/proper way to vertically align the text in the middle of its column? The image height is statically set in the CSS.

I have tried setting an outer div to `display: table` and an inner div to `display: table-cell` with `vertical-align: middle` but that didn't work either.

[image]

**HTML**

```
<section id="browse" class="browse">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-5">
                <h2 class="text-left">Link up with other gamers all over the world who share the same tastes in games.</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-1"></div>
            <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-7 animation_container">
                <img id="animation_img2" class="animation_img animation_img2" src="images/section2img2.png"/>
                <img id="animation_img1" class="animation_img animation_img1" src="images/section2img1.png"/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

**CSS**

```
.browse .container, .blind_dating .container { padding-bottom: 0; }
.animation_container { position: relative; }
.browse .animation_container { height: 430px; }
.animation_img { position: absolute; bottom: 0; }
.animation_img1 { right: 25%; }
.animation_img2 { right: 25%; }
```

Answer (score 38, accepted):

**HTML:**

First, we will need to add a class to your text container so that we can access and style it accordingly.

```
<div class="col-xs-5 textContainer">
     <h3 class="text-left">Link up with other gamers all over the world who share the same tastes in games.</h3>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

Next, we will apply the following styles to align it vertically, according to the size of the image div next to it.

```
.textContainer { 
    height: 345px; 
    line-height: 340px;
}

.textContainer h3 {
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

All Done! Adjust the line-height and height on the styles above if you believe that it is still slightly out of align.

**[WORKING EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/yg0Lhhju/463/)**

Comment: @TheNomad - Anytime! Yeah it's a very good trick to keep in mind for vertical aligning.

Answer (score 10):

```
h2.text-left{
  position:relative;
  top:50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

**Explanation:**

The **top:50%** style essentially pushes the header element down 50% from the top of the parent element.  The translateY stylings also act in a similar manner by moving then element down 50% from the top.

Please note that this works well for headers with 1 (maybe 2) lines of text as this simply moves the **top** of the header element down 50% and then the rest of the content fills in below that, which means that with multiple lines of text it would appear to be slightly below vertically aligned.

A possible fix for multiple lines would be to use a percentage slightly less than 50%.

Answer (score 0):

Could you not have simply added:

```
align-items:center;
```

to a new class in your row div. Essentially:

```
<div class="row align_center">

.align_center { align-items:center; }
```