# Bootstrap center div to other's

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using a template with Bootstrap.

The following code:

```
<div class="row mix-grid thumbnails wrapper white" id="pictures_placeholder">
            <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 mix ">
                <div class="mix-inner">
                    <img class="img-responsive" src="../../../assets/admin/pages/media/works/img1.jpg"
                         alt="">

                    <div class="mix-details picture-bottom-label">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12">
                                <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-3">
                                    <img src="../../../assets/admin/pages/media/profile/profile_user.jpg"
                                         class="img-responsive img-circle profile-pic"
                                         alt=""
                                            />
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-8 col-xs-8 text-left user-name">Asaf Nevo</div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

does this:

[image]

How can I make the name (Asaf Nevo) to be entered to the image ?

Comment: you want the name in the image?

Comment: You mean vertically aligned in the middle?

Comment: @Chanckjh I want it vertically aligned

Comment: @ReneS yes that what i want

Comment: You can easily do it by adding your custom CSS external or inline CSS

Answer (score 0):

try adding this to CSS:

```
div.user-name{height:92px;line-height:92px;}
```

hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Put the name in the same div as the image. Make both inline.

```
<img src="../../../assets/admin/pages/media/profile/profile_user.jpg"
    class="img-responsive img-circle profile-pic" alt="" />Asav Nevo
```

Now play with the CSS property [vertical-align](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_vertical-align.asp). Something like `vertical-align: middle` could work and yes, this property should be applied to the surrounding div if not mistaken, potentially also to the inline content itself. I cannot try it right now.

Comment: Bootstrap cannot do everything, check these out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20547819/vertical-align-with-bootstrap-3 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25538732/bootstrap-how-to-get-text-to-vertical-align-in-a-div-container http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18192114/how-to-use-vertical-align-in-bootstrap

Answer (score 0):

Add this to the `css`:

```
.user-name {
  margin-top:50%;
}
```